# Landscape sends internal emails, cannot remove

Tags: postfix, landscape

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server that is continuously sending emails which I can see in `/var/log/mail.log`. I might have had this server configured to use Landscape at some point in the past, but I am not actually using it.

(The server has a Postfix SMTP relay set up, and these messages are relayed to an outside API, from where they are blocked. I would like to prevent those mails from being sent at all.)

Every five minutes, logs like this appear:

```
Jul 13 06:30:01 worker postfix/pickup[24215]: 133EB3EEDC: uid=108 from=<landscape>
Jul 13 06:30:01 worker postfix/cleanup[31293]: 133EB3EEDC: message-id=<20220713043001.133EB3EEDC@worker>
Jul 13 06:30:01 worker postfix/qmgr[17763]: 133EB3EEDC: from=<landscape@worker>, size=908, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 13 06:30:01 worker postfix/local[31295]: 133EB3EEDC: to=<landscape@worker>, orig_to=<landscape>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.02/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Jul 13 06:30:01 worker postfix/qmgr[17763]: 133EB3EEDC: removed
```

I have the following landscape-related packages available:

```
➜  ~ apt list | grep landscape

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

aws-status/bionic,bionic 0.2.3+159-0landscape1~25~ubuntu18.04.1 all
landscape-api/bionic,bionic 19.01-0ubuntu1 all
landscape-client/bionic 18.03~1075~git.256ad02~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64
landscape-common/bionic 18.03~1075~git.256ad02~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [residual-config]
landscape-hashids/bionic,bionic 19.01-0ubuntu1 all
landscape-hosted/bionic 19.01.1-0ubuntu1 amd64
landscape-server/bionic 19.01.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [residual-config]
landscape-server-quickstart/bionic 19.01.1-0ubuntu1 amd64
python-commandant/bionic 0.5.1~bzr4-0landscape1~bzr66~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64
python-convoy/bionic,bionic,now 0.4.4ubuntu1~bzr39-0landscape2~bzr12~ubuntu18.04.1 all [residual-config]
python-stripe/bionic,bionic 429-0~landscape+1~ubuntu18.04.1 all
python-txaws/bionic,bionic 0.2.3+159-0landscape1~25~ubuntu18.04.1 all
```

Yet, when I attempt to uninstall `landscape-common`, I get:

```
➜  ~ apt remove landscape-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'landscape-common' is not installed, so not removed
```

No process related to `landscape` can be found:

```
➜  ~ ps -ef | grep landscape
```

I do note that there is a crontab in `/etc/cron.d/landscape-server` which does this every five minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * landscape ( /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/update_alerts.sh; /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/landscape_profiles.sh; /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/process_alerts.sh )
```

How can I get rid of Landscape then? There is a `landscape` user but I don't want to just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently had installed Landscape at some point but never really uninstalled it properly. Given that there is no documentation on how to uninstall it, what I ended up doing was:

```
dpkg --purge landscape-server
```

This also removed the crontab files that generated the mail traffic.